# Functional Derivative ${\delta q_a(t)}/{\delta q_b(t')}$

Tags: functional-analysis, physics, functional-calculus

$\newcommand{\fdv}[2]{\frac{\delta #1}{\delta #2}}$
$\newcommand{\dv}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d} #1}{\mathrm{d}#2}}$
$\newcommand{\pdv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$

I'm from a physics background and I've always known the definition to be related to the Euler-Lagrange Equations i.e.

$$\fdv {L(q,\dot q)} {q(t)} = \pdv{L}{q} - \dv{}{t} \pdv{L}{\dot q} \; ,$$

where $\dot q$ denotes the derivative of the function $q$ with respect to $t$.

However with this definition I cannot prove a fact that I've seen in a lecture video about Quantum Field Theory, which is

$$\fdv{q_a(t)}{q_b(t')} = \delta_{ab} \delta(t-t') \; , \tag 1$$

where $\delta(t-t')$ is the Dirac delta function/distribution and $\delta_{ab}$ is the Kroneker delta.

I don't know how I should make sense out of this equation let alone prove it because $q_a(t)$ is not a functional but a *function*. I'd appreciate if someone can explain what is meant by the equation (1) and give a proof thereof.

Comment: The discrepancy lies in that actually **almost nobody(!!)** knows how to read these lines!!! That missconception starts already from sloppy taught mechanics classes. *(Let me outline it as answer.)*

Comment: Besides it is not even a function but only a number. ;)

Comment: You seem to have lost track of the fact that the Euler-Lagrange equation has hypotheses. Namely, along the path from a fixed point $a$ to a fixed point $b$ which minimizes the quantity $\int_0^1 L(t,q(t),q'(t)) dt$, the Euler-Lagrange equation is satisfied. But the fact that these points are held fixed is essential, in that it forces $q(0)=a$ and $q(1)=b$, and therefore forces the admissible variations to satisfy $v(0)=v(1)=0$.

Comment: @Ian: Just to remark: That won't help him since there's basically no proof as these are, simply put, conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First have a look at:*

**Integral Argument**

> For enough variations:
>   $$\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty:\quad\int_0^T\varphi(s)\delta\varphi(s)\mathrm{d}s=0\quad(\delta\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_0)\implies\varphi(t)\equiv0$$

That is needed for Euler-Lagrange!

*Now go carefully through:*

**Detailed Calculation**

> *Directional* derivative:
>   $$\frac{\delta}{\delta q}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial\delta q}:=\partial_{\delta q}$$

Consider as example:
$$\mathcal{L}:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}:\quad\mathcal{L}(u,v;w):=\frac12mv^2-\frac{1}{w}u^2$$

For *partial* derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial u}=-\frac{1}{w}2u\quad\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial v}=mv\quad\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial w}=\frac{1}{w^2}u^2$$

Introduce evaluations:
$$\eta_a:\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}:\quad\eta_a[q]:=q(a)$$
$$\vartheta_a:\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}:\quad\vartheta_a[q]:=\dot{q}(a)$$
$$\omega_a:\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}:\quad\omega_a[q]:=a$$

For *directional* derivative:
$$\frac{\delta\eta_a}{\delta q}[q]=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\{\eta_a[q+\varepsilon\delta q]-\eta_a[q]\}=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\{q(a)+\varepsilon\delta q(a)-q(a)\}=\delta q(a)$$
$$\frac{\delta\vartheta_a}{\delta q}[q]=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\{\vartheta_a[q+\varepsilon\delta q]-\vartheta_a[q]\}\stackrel{*}{=}\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\{\dot{q}(a)+\varepsilon\dot{\delta q}(a)-\dot{q}(a)\}=\dot{\delta q}(a)$$
$$\frac{\delta\omega_a}{\delta q}[q]=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\{\omega_a[q+\varepsilon\delta q]-\omega_a[q]\}=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\{a-a\}=0$$

Consider the action:
$$S[q]:=\int_0^T\mathcal{L}(\eta_s[q],\vartheta_s[q];s)\mathrm{d}s=:\int_0^T\hat{\mathcal{L}_s}[q]\mathrm{d}s\quad(q\in\mathcal{C}^\infty)$$

Suppose variations:
$$\mathcal{C}^\infty_0:=\{\delta q\in\mathcal{C}^\infty:\delta q(0)=\delta q(T)=0\}$$

For *directional* derivative:
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta q}[q]=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\{S[q+\varepsilon\delta q]-S[q]\}\\
=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_0^T\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\bigg\{\mathcal{L}(\eta_s[q+\varepsilon\delta q],\vartheta_s[q+\varepsilon\delta q];s)\mathrm{d}s-\mathcal{L}(\eta_s[q],\vartheta_s[q];s)\bigg\}\mathrm{d}s\\
\stackrel{**}{=}\int_0^T\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\bigg\{\mathcal{L}(\eta_s[q+\varepsilon\delta q],\vartheta_s[q+\varepsilon\delta q];s)\mathrm{d}s-\mathcal{L}(\eta_s[q],\vartheta_s[q];s)\bigg\}\mathrm{d}s\\
=\int_0^T\frac{\delta\hat{\mathcal{L}_s}}{\delta q}[q]\mathrm{d}s=\int_0^T\bigg\{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial u}\frac{\delta\eta_s}{\delta q}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial v}\frac{\delta\vartheta_s}{\delta q}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial w}\frac{\delta\omega_s}{\delta q}\bigg\}\mathrm{d}s\\
=\int_0^T\bigg\{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial u}\delta q(s)+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial v}\dot{\delta q}(s)+0\bigg\}\mathrm{d}s=\int_0^T\bigg\{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial u}\delta q(s)+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial v}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\delta q(s)\bigg\}\mathrm{d}s\\
=\int_0^T\bigg\{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial u}\delta q(s)-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial v}\delta q(s)\bigg\}\mathrm{d}s=\int_0^T\bigg\{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial u}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial v}\bigg\}\delta q(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

By the integral argument:
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta q}[q]=0\quad(\delta q\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_0)\implies\bigg\{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial u}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial v}\bigg\}=0$$

Concluding Euler-Lagrange.

*Next try it sombolically:*

**Symbolic Calculation**

Regard action functional:
$$S[q]:=\int\mathcal{L}(q(s),\dot{q}(s);s)\mathrm{d}s\quad(q\in\mathcal{C}^\infty)$$

Its derivite writes:
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta q}=\int\bigg\{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial q}\frac{\delta q}{\delta q}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{q}}\frac{\delta\dot{q}}{\delta q}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial t}\frac{\delta t}{\delta q}\bigg\}\delta q\mathrm{d}s\\
=\int\bigg\{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial q}\delta q+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{q}}\dot{\delta q}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial t}0\bigg\}\delta q\mathrm{d}s=\int\bigg\{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial q}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{q}}\bigg\}\delta q\mathrm{d}s$$

By the integral argument:
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta q}=0\quad(\delta q\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_0)\implies\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta q}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta q}$$

Concluding Euler-Lagrange.

*Finally try to shorten it by:*

**Shortened Calculation**

Regard action functional:
$$S[q]:=\int\mathcal{L}(q(s),\dot{q}(s);s)\mathrm{d}s\quad(q\in\mathcal{C}^\infty)$$

> For *singular* variations:
>   $$\delta q_a\notin\mathcal{C}^\infty_0:\quad\delta q_a(t):=\delta(t-a)$$

Agree on the *convention*:
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta q(a)}:=\frac{\delta S}{\delta q_a}\quad\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial q(t)}:=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial q}(t)\quad\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{q}(t)}:=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{q}}(t)\quad\frac{\delta q(t)}{\delta q(a)}:=\frac{\delta q}{\delta q_a}(t)$$

By the previous calculation:
$$0=\frac{\delta S}{\delta q(t)}=\int\bigg\{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial q(s)}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{q}(s)}\bigg\}\frac{\delta q(s)}{\delta q(t)}\mathrm{d}s\\
=\int\bigg\{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial q(s)}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{q}(s)}\bigg\}\delta(s-t)\mathrm{d}s=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial q(t)}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{q}(t)}$$

That killed the integral argument!

*...now you're ready for QFT. ;)*

**Linearity of derivative!*

***Regularity of Lagrangian!*

Comment: Trust me: Try to follow the second part carefully!!

Comment: I followed you answer to almost to the very end, which by the way I should say an excellent answer. I just didn't get the part with singular variations. Why do I choose my function $q_a$ to be the dirac delta function?  I'm talking about the last orange box: $\delta q_a\notin\mathcal{C}^\infty_0:\quad q_a(t):=\delta(t-a)$

Comment: Because you want to overleap the integral argument and end up immediately at Euler-Lagrange. That way it is not rigid but it does its job. In case one requires rigorosity one can still do the derivation properly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\delta q_a$ instead of $q_a$?

Comment: Oh right, thanks! *(Corrected.)*

Comment: By the way I don't think people in physics classes are too interested in mathematical rigour. ;)

Comment: Hahaha ya ^^ ..besides, do you know Noether's theorem? I mean the general version for fields where you get this huge expression with all the inertial coordinate transformations, relative and total variation, etc. etc.. There too almost nobody knows what they're actually doing. Noether's theorem in its most general vein is simple as an egg. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fix $t=t_0$, so you can pointwise identify $q_a(t_0)$ with a functional $$\mathcal F[u]=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathrm d t' u(t')\delta(t_0-t')$$ as $q_a(t_0)\equiv\mathcal F[q_a]$. Then you have the "Euler-Lagrange equation": $$\frac{\delta \mathcal F[q_a]}{\delta q_b(t')}=\frac{\partial}{\partial q_b(t')}q_a(t')\delta(t_0-t')$$
the same as for a Lagrangian (the $d/dt\dots$ part is of course missing). Now finally, using $\partial q_a(t')/\partial q_b(t')=\delta_{ab}$, the result follows.

Comment: The Dirac measure has no derivative and therefore the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation is meaningless then. Rather one exploits the fundamental theorem of calculus of variations.

Comment: It has weak derivatives

Comment: Yes, but the result is the same. I wanted to appeal to what OP knows

Comment: Yep but that is simply overkill: The whole thing works on the basis of ordinary calculus.

Comment: And besides I assume the OP is not familiar with distribution theory.

Comment: @Freeze_S: You are right, I'm not familiar with distribution theory.

Comment: @gonenc: Distributions are also absolutely unnecessary and overkill for deriving Euler-Lagrange - even in the context of QFT!!

Comment: Well you need some integral kernel to identify a function and a functional, and dirac deltas hardly require any knowlegde of distribution theory. Here you can just take heuristically a singular Lagrangian if you don't want to get deeper in detail. Whatever floats your boat i guess :)

Comment: Also, OP, think of the delta in this case as the continuous analogue of the kronecker. You will probably see it used that way the most in cases as these. Certain commutators might simply be defined as being a delta of the arguments of the operators, for example!